# STMFD/LDMFD not restoring register values?

Tags: assembly, arm

Why is the register r5 not being restored to its original value in the code below? It is set to #14, then modified in the subroutine, and when the subroutine completes the value is set to 0 in r5.

```
        mov r5, #14
        bl func ; Call subroutine func so that it can execute the calculations required.

endless b endless ;End the program after the subroutine completes.

func    STMFD sp!,{r5-r7} ;Save working registers in a safe place while the subroutine uses them for calculations.
        mov r5, #66
        add r0, r0, r1 ;Subroutine code.

        LDMFD sp!,{r5-r7}
        mov pc, lr ;Return from subroutine.
```

Comment: You must be checking the value of `r5` incorrectly. Assuming `sp` is set correctly, that code should work.

Comment: sp is probably the issue then, I found this example and it was only part of a program. How do I setup sp?

Comment: Depends on your environment. If you run this on a normal OS, you should already have a working `sp`. Otherwise, make sure it points to the top of some writable memory.

Comment: Hm, that is odd. I am using ARM, Big Endian, Keil v4.

Comment: Verify the stack contains the value of `r5` (ie. `14`) after the `STMFD`. Then verify that `LDMFD` loads it back.

Comment: r5 contains the value 14 after STMFD. LDMFD does not load it back, it instead sets r5 to 0.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I asked if the value `14` is **written to the stack** (look in memory!).

Comment: No values are being modified in memory when STMFD/LDMFD executes. (no red highlighting/green highlighting). I do not see 0E anywhere.Do I have to adjust the memory map? I am still learning these things ;;

Comment: Look at where `sp` is pointing, that should be where the write occurs. Make sure it points to writable memory. *Technically since you use FD stack, the modified bytes will be from the `sp` down.

Comment: `sp` points at `0xFFFFFFEC` after `STMFD` executes. The memory location `0xFFFFFFEC` has its values change to light green after `STMFD` executes, however they all remain `00`. They turn a solid green when `LDMFD` executes, however once again, they all remain `00`. Weird, looks like it is a writable location.